# How to update the PHP settings on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, configuration, settings, php-ini

I develop on a VM (with Debian 7), but in the current project, I have to user Composer from my Windows 7 host system. To do this I "installed" PHP (downloaded and saved in `C:\Program Files\php-5.6.8-Win32-VC11-x64`). As futher step I downloaded the Composer installer for Windows and started the `Composer-Setup.exe` -- and got an error:

> Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
>   Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:
>
> The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
>   If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

OK. The `php_openssl.dll` in the `ext` folder. I created `php.ini` from the `php.ini-production` and enabled the line `extension=php_openssl.dll`. But no effect. The OpenSSL modle is still not in the active modules list (`php -m`). I also tried to change the `ext` folder, but also this setting is not getting updated.

What should one do, in order to change PHP settings on Windows?

Comment: Verify that you modified the correct `php.ini` file. On windows I think it's possible there is a `php.ini` file hiding in system32 or some similar os directory.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have `extension_dir` set as well, otherwise PHP will look for the extensions in an incorrect location.

The `php.ini-production` file has this (commented out) by default:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
; extension_dir = "ext"
```

Comment: I've activated `extension_dir = "ext"` everywhere: in `C:\Program Files\php-5.6.8-Win32-VC11-x64\php.ini`, `php.ini-production`, `php.ini-development`, and in `C:\Windows\php.ini`. But is still not working.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have a `php.ini` in your `Windows` directory.  Try renaming that file out of the way and see if that helps.